# Image quality loss

Tags: android

When I save the image on sdcard then Image quality is lost

Here is my code for the same

```
Bitmap bitmap2 = extras.getParcelable("data");
File file = new File(path);
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

Comment: its got after using Android default crop

com.android.camera.action.CROP

Comment: for croup just use foloowing lib its so easy https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

Comment: But it works good on other apps like whats app

Comment: this is very wearied that default   com.android.camera.action.CROP is not giving good quality image.Vote for my question also

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609275/android-camera-intent-low-bitmap-quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to lose quality, save your file as PNG which is a lossless compression format:

```
bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
```

Comment: I changed it still  same issue