# Android Low picture quality after shot

Tags: android, local-storage, android-camera, resolution, blurry

I have a button that triggers an image capture :

```
private void capturePicture() {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Tiến hành gọi Capture Image intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    } else ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 200);
}
```

Right after I take the shot, I see the capture and the resolution is very low. It is  saved in the local storage and when it is displayed in the app it's not in its original quality.

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path, int position, Device device)
{

    try {
        File f=new File(path,device.getSerial()+".jpg");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        imvDeviceImage.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

An here is for the permission

```
 if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    } else ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 200);
```

[image: After shooting]
[image: In the app]

Comment: You may use URI instead of bitmap

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34960746/5156075

Comment: Try this solution from this post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382217/1855635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use File provider option for the same.

In the manifest file add the provider description :

```
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/image_path" />
    </provider>
```

add the permission :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

add a path file( i have made image_path.xml, added in the description of file provider) under res/xml folder. (if xml is not there, make one folder named xml.)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="captured_image"
        path="Gallery/MyImages/" />
</paths>
```

Add dangerous permission request procedure for devices above lollipop, since WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is a dangerous permission.

In the class, in which you initiate Camera :

Declare a contant to pass in camera intent:

```
private int ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA = 8765;
  private String CAPTURE_IMAGE_FILE_PROVIDER = "YOUR_PACKAGE.fileprovider";
```

Now, you can pass the uri instead in the camera intent.

```
    public void launchCamera() {
// check for dangerous permission 
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            File path = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), "Gallery/MyImages/");
            if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs();
            File image = new File(path, "image_capture.jpg");
            Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity.getApplicationContext(), CAPTURE_IMAGE_FILE_PROVIDER, image);
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            providePermissionForProvider(cameraIntent, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        } else {
            //if permission is not provided
            new PermissionsMarshmallow(activity);
        }
    }
```

::Edited :

forgot to add this function :

```
 private void providePermissionForProvider(Intent intent, Uri uri) {
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        activity.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
}
```

In the onActivityResult function :

```
//get the file from the uri path  , it is the same declared in the path file in xml folder. in this case it is Gallery/MyImages/
     File path = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), "Gallery/MyImages/");
                    if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs();
                    File imageFile = new File(path, "image_capture.jpg");

                    Uri stringUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);

                    Bitmap bitmapFromMedia = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), stringUri);
```

Hope this helps. let me know if you opt for this procedure and are stuck somewhere.